# SQL SERVER Upivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I'm trying to unpivot this table but I always get an error.

Does somebody a solution for this ?

The result has to be like this, 3 columns ID / question (q) / total number of these row

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QPhc.png)

Comment: Where is the error ? Can you show us ? What is the expected result ?

Comment: Hi, [Tour], [ask] , and [mre]. Are your best bet for now in order to have an answerable question. You can simply build a simple example table in excel and the expected output. that will be the first step. You should really provide enought information to reproduce the issue [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Note that picture of code are not great. We can't copy past or anything. It's like showing  pictures of your car to a mechanic.

Comment: My bad, I talked about Excel and you jumped on it.
Missing 2 things the simplification of your data "minimal".
For example I googled for pivot and took a [random question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query). 
The data is clear and understandable. 
In your question there is no obvious link between the 2 pictures dataset. The id doesn't match. 

2nd the "no picture" policy. It can be incredibly painfull to hand type every data from the picture in order to craft an answer. 
But you have access to copy-past.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` :

```
select cc.q2 as id_cc, cq.*
from src.qa_data_cc cc cross apply
     ( values (cc.q77, 'q77'), (cc.q78, 'q78'), 
              (cc.q79, 'q79'), (cc.q80, 'q80'),
               . . .
     ) cq(cols, colname);
```